# What is the minimum penalty for a class A misdemeanor in the states of Missouri and Oregon?

Tags: oregon, sentencing, missouri

The maxiumum jail time is listed on such sites:
https://romanolawpc.com/misdemeanor-crimes-oregon/
https://carvercantin.com/missouri-misdemeanor/#class-a
but the minimum jail time/fines are not listed on those sites.

The case in question is one of "tampering with computer data" or "unauthorized access to computer systems" and there is no damage to the company in question.

Is there a minimum or can the judge choose to not sentence jail time/fines?

Answer (score 1):

[These are the crimes](http://www.crimevictimsunited.org/measure11/presentation/pdf/sentences.pdf) in Oregon that are subject to mandatory minimum sentencing. All Class A misdemeanors have a maximum prison sentence of [364 days](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/161.615) and [$6,250](https://www.oregonlaws.org/ors/161.635), but all of the minimum-sentence crimes have minima substantially above that -- the two classes of crime do not intersect. Therefore, no fine and no jail time are mandatory.

Under the [revised minimum sentencing law](https://famm.org/wp-content/uploads/MO-HB-192-Enacted-Bill-Summary.pdf) in Missouri, the set of crimes triggering minimum sentencing has been shrunk. It does seem to interest partially with some crimes that can be Class A misdemeanors ([resisting or interfering with arrest](https://law.justia.com/codes/missouri/2005/t38/5750000150.html)) but the list does not include "unauthorized access to computer systems". So again, there is no minimum and no jail / fine is a possibility.